# Why am I able to assign tasks to LOCAL SERVICE in TFS 2008?

Tags: tfs

I'm not 100% sure it wasn't always this way and I never noticed... but I'm pretty sure this is new and something got messed up somewhere.

I am able to assign work items to a user named LOCAL SERVICE (see screenshot) in TFS 2008 (Workgroup Edition).  This seems wrong, but I have no idea how to fix the issue.

It's not the end of the world, but it's bugging me.

Thanks in advance for any help.

[image: TFS - LOCAL SERVICE user]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the Assigned To list comes from the members of the Team Project group called "Contributors". If you right-click the Team Project, choose Team Project Settings and then Group Membership and check the members of the Contributors group. If you can't see it in there try using TFSSecurity.exe:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE>tfssecurity /imx
n:"[TeamProjectName]\Contributors" /server:ServerNameOrUrl
```

Regards,

William D. Bartholomew (Team System MVP)

Comment: I keep getting "Error: The identity cannot be resolved." with tfssecurity because LOCAL SERVICE is not coming up in the GUI. After I type the command in I get prompted for username and password, but it never authenticates. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like LOCAL SERVICE is not a contributor (see below).  I guess I must have changed a default setting or something.

Identity type: Windows user
   Logon name: NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE
 Display name: LOCAL SERVICE

Member of 3 group(s):
a [A] [SERVER]\Team Foundation Administrators
s [A] [SERVER]\Service Accounts
e [A] [SERVER]\Team Foundation Valid Users

Comment: Actually, the default list of users comes from [SERVER]\Team Foundation Valid Users NOT [TeamProjectName]\Contributors as I originally stated.

This blog post might help you out:
http://dotnet.org.za/willy/archive/2008/09/17/tfs-why-is-the-quot-assignedto-quot-drop-down-listing-gazillion-users.aspx

Comment: @William no need for signature and regards sir (: